# Hide ActionBar Tab in Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have an Android App which shows some Tabs in ActionBar. Now I want to hide one Tab and only after a Button-Click-Event (or something else) I would like to show this Tab.
In this example "Section 2" should be invisible from start-up and after Button-press it should be visible.

[image]

Here is the current code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

How to do this during livetime?

Comment: I started writing a answer, but then it hit me. Why do you do this? If you do this you will have bad user experience. In my mind you can let the tabs have 3 items, and then if you go to the tab that needs to be hidden, display a "locked" fragment. I have never seen tabs that have changeable number of tabs

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
((ViewGroup) tablayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

> TabLayout is A layout that arranges its children into rows and columns. A TableLayout consists of a number of TableRow objects, each defining a row. TableLayout containers do not display border lines for their rows, columns, or cells. Each row has zero or more cells; each cell can hold one View object. The table has as many columns as the row with the most cells

`TabLayout` is a `Viewgroup` just like `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` but it arranges its childs in rows and columns

**this will hide the middle tab "SECTION 2"**

```
((ViewGroup) tablayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
//show
    ((ViewGroup) tablayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```